# Implementing JavaHelp Search with the NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, javahelp

I have integrated javahelp online documentation 
 into my desktop application with the NetBeans IDE.
 I have the topic files and the navigation files as well.
 The javahelp folder was not installed rather bin files 
 copied from the folder were added to the application as library files.
The topic files and navigation files were added to the project source folder.

Most of the workdone was based on the tutorials from this site 
 http://weblogs.java.net/blog/pkeegan/archive/2007/05/javahelp_and_sw.html

now I want to implement the javahelp search engine 
 from the NetBeans IDE

So that the search engine can be created automatically. 
Rather than from the command prompt.

any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to write a program that makes use of the `com.sun.java.help.search.Indexer` class. Its `main()` method is what gets executed when you run the [`jhindexer`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/author/jhindexer.html) command.

The `Indexer` class has no official documentation, but here are some hints (from the documentation of the HelpSetMaker SF project): http://helpsetmaker.sourceforge.net/userdoc/doc55.html.

The full (GPL-licensed) source code for the HelpSetMaker project is here: http://publicgit.cantamen.de/?p=helpsetmaker. In particular, check out the `createHelpsetSearchIndex()` method of [OutputCreatorThread.java](http://publicgit.cantamen.de/?p=helpsetmaker;a=blob;f=java/de/cantamen/helpsetmaker/engine/OutputCreatorThread.java;hb=HEAD) .